# How to call & use ERC20 airdrop smartcontract

Tags: solidity, remix, myetherwallet, compiler, airdrop

I'm using [remix solidity browser compiler](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.4.19+commit.c4cbbb05.js).

I deployed this code for an AirDrop smart contract:
https://pastebin.com/kzYxmEab

I used the same address to create/deploy the Airdrop contract as was used to create/deploy the token contract. I sent a test amount of the token to the Airdrop Contract, also from the same address as created it.

I want to use the sendTokens() function to send multiple at a time eg.
["A","B","C","D"],[2,4,6,8]

Where and how *exactly* do I actually *use* and interact with this contract? Is it from within Remix compiler? Is it from within MyEtherWallet, while logged in with MetaMask of the creator address, by using the ABI/json box there?

[Tx Hash](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x07304cd73763d4ac87ed2f719940f34797fdabe00c3c6e2d60e4d9b2b4da9273) of the AirDrop contract deployed.

thanks

Comment: verify your contract!

Comment: I'm having trouble doing that, I can't. I must have changed something minor - would a change in just the comment lines in the code affect it?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK parity works best with interacting with this Airdrop contract. Mist is an option but it is buggy and tokens may not be sent.